# For which positive $k$, $3k+1$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

As in the title, for which positive integers $k$, $3k+1$ is prime?
I think that $k$ at least cannot be $k=2m+1$, because then $3(2m+1)+1=6m+4=2(3m+2)$, which is not a prime number, so we got to look at even numbers $k$.

It also cannot be of form $k=10m+8$, because then $3(10m+8)+1=30m+25=5(6m+5)$, which is not a prime number.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type of answer are you looking for? A condition on $k$ such that $3k+1$ is prime?

Comment: Was this task assigned to you or did you think of it? Because it seems rather hard :)

Comment: There is no evident pattern to give a satisfactory answer. This question is as hard as "which positive numbers are prime?", which is somehow unsolved.

Comment: To be exact, I'm looking for such set $A$, that "$k \in A \Leftrightarrow p \text{ is prime}$".

Comment: You can find few elements of $A$ like $k=2,4,6,8,10,12,14,20$.But the whole set $A$ is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do know that there are infinitely many primes of the form $3k+1$ by Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, but we do not know how this set looks like. In fact, we do not even know explicitly how the set of *all* primes looks like, i.e., taking the progression $a_k=k$ instead of $a_k=3k+1$ we cannot give a formula to say that $k\in A \Leftrightarrow p \text{ is prime}$. We can say, it starts with $k=2,3,5,7,11,13,\ldots,$ and there are infinitely many of them, and locally they behave very irregular, but globally they behave very regular, with the law $k/\log(k)$ etc.